# How can I order the rows that I pull from a Salesforce object using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've got this looping ampscript retrieving rows from Salesforce object below. And I'm trying to figure out if we can retrieve them in an ordered lookup? Like a LookUpOrderRows function would work.

[image: screen capture of looping email content attached]

```
%%[ 
Var @RackPrice, @RackPriceRow, @BatchID__c, @Effective_Date__c, @Terminal_Number__c, @Terminal_Name__c, @Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c, @i

Set @RackPrice = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("rack_price_notification__c","Terminal_Number__c,Effective_Date__c,Terminal_Name__c,Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c","Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c", "=", @AccountId,"BatchID__c", "=", @BatchID) 

if RowCount(@RackPrice) > 0 then 
For @i=1 TO RowCount(@RackPrice) DO 
Set @RackPriceRow = Row(@RackPrice, @i) 

Set @Effective_Date__c = FIELD(@RackPriceRow,"Effective_Date__c")
Set @Terminal_Number__c = FIELD(@RackPriceRow,"Terminal_Number__c")
Set @Terminal_Name__c = FIELD(@RackPriceRow,"Terminal_Name__c")
Set @Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c = FIELD(@RackPriceRow,"Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c")
]%% 

Effective_Date__c: %%=FormatDate(@Effective_Date__c, 'mm-d-yyyy')=%%<br>
Terminal_Number__c: %%=v(@Terminal_Number__c)=%%<br>
Terminal_Name__c: %%=v(@Terminal_Name__c)=%%<br>
Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c: %%=v(@Rack_Notification_Sold_To__c)=%%
<br><br>

%%[
/* nested loop for links data retrieve */ 
NEXT @i endif ]%%
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, retrieving ordered rows from a SF Object is not possible  AMPScript.

I'd probably write a [**SSJS Script Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/server_side_javascript_activity/) to write your SF data and store it in a Data Extension.  Then you can retrieve it with a [**LookupOrderedRows()**](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/LookupOrderedRows.html) function in your email or landing page.

I suppose you could also mix SSJS and AMPScript and build your result-set as a JSON object and use SSJS to sort it, but that seems more heroic than the SSJS Activity.